# Jboss Wildfly migration Resteasy error

Tags: jboss, wildfly, resteasy, classnotfoundexception

I'm currently migrating from Jboss 6 to Jboss 10.1 and keep running into the same error when trying to deploy:

```
14:39:10,147 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mucrdtxnws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mucrdtxnws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher from [Module "deployment.fis-txnreceiver-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT-DEV.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher from [Module "deployment.fis-txnreceiver-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT-DEV.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
    ... 6 more
```

I have tried removing resteasy from my pom and excluding it from the jboss-deployment structure but I still receive the same error. Please tell me someone has run into this problem before and fixed it.

Comment: Have you defined the correct `resteasy` module in your  `jboss-deployment structure` and in the pom the same version as in Wildfly? Seems like the dependency/module is not loaded as the app deploys.

Comment: If you have any references to resteasy components in your web.xml then you should remove them as well. They're almost certainly redundant now